# How to secure web api with Identity Server 3

Tags: asp.net-web-api, identityserver3

I'm building an MVC web app that uses the openID Connect hybrid flow to authenticate with Identity Server 3. The MVC web app contains jQuery scripts to get async JSON data from een ApiController. That ApiController is part of the same MVC web app.

I don't want that everyone is able to access the data from the API, so I want to secure the API as well. I added an [authorize] attribute to the ApiController. When requesting the API with a JQuery ajax request I get the following error message:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://localhost:44371/identity/connect/authorize?....etc.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:13079' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

But, when I do a request to the API method directly in browser, I will be correct redirected to the Login page of Identity Server..

So, what's exactly the problem here? I read something about that requesting the /authorize endpoint is not allowed via 'back-channel', but I don't understand what's the difference between 'front-channel' and 'back-channel'. Is it possible that I mixed up the wrong OAuth flows? Is the Hybrid flow not the correct one maybe?

I also find out that the API is often a seperate app, but is it always neccessary / best-practice to build a seperate API app that for example requires a bearer token?

Please point me in the right direction about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The authorize method on your identity server does not allow ajax calls. Even specifying CORS headers is not going to help you in this particular case. Perhaps you could return a forbidden response instead of a redirect and manually redirect the client to the desired location via window.location

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow your IdentityServer to be accessed from other domains, this is done by allowing "Cross Origin Resource Sharing" or CORS for short. In IdentityServer the simplest way to allow this is in your Client configuration for your Javascript Client, see this from the [IdentityServer docs on CORS](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/topics/cors.html):

> One approach to configuing CORS is to use the AllowedCorsOrigins collection on the client configuration. Simply add the origin of the client to the collection and the default configuration in IdentityServer will consult these values to allow cross-origin calls from the origins.

The error you're seeing is the browser telling you that when it asked IdentityServer if it allows requests from your Javscript client, it returned a response basically saying no, because the origin (http://localhost:13079) was not specified in the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" response header. In fact that header wasn't in the response at all meaning CORS is not enabled.

If you follow the quickstart for adding a JavaScript client from the docs [here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/7_javascript_client.html?highlight=cors) all the necessary code is detailed there that you need for the Client config and to setup IdentityServer to allow CORS.